# Create 2 methods or 1 method with arguments

Tags: php, function, oop, functional-programming

When writing class methods to set a variable to true/false, is it better to write separate methods for each [setActiveTrue() and setActiveFalse()], or is it preferable to use a single method that takes a true/false argument [setActive($x)].

```
public setActive() {
    $this->activeElement = true;
}

public removeActive() {
    $this->activeElement = false;
}
```

OR

```
public setActive($x) {
    $this->activeElement = $x;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged C#.  You'd use a single property `bool Active { get; set; }` in C#.

Comment: If you go for a single `setActive()` method, explicitly cast the argument to `Boolean` rather than trusting that it will always be a Boolean that's passed in

Comment: I'd make the methods `Activate()` and `Deactivate()` to make it clear what you're trying to actually do.

Comment: I would go with setStatus($active). If $active is true you are activating. If not, you are inactivating.

Comment: This kind of thing is subjective. If you're looking for answers based on some principles or coding practices, you might want to check out [codereview.se] — make sure to read their help center before posting though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "best practice" is, but I always do one method such as:

```
public function setActive ($active = true) {
    $this->_active = (boolean) $active;
}
```

I can see both sides of the argument, but my style is one method.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
public function Active($x = true) {
    $this->activeElement = $x;
}
```

Then you can call `Active()` to set it active and `Active(false)` to set it to not active.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have a single method to set and get:

```
public function active($param='')
 {switch ($param)
   {case '':
      return $this->active;
    case true:
      $this->active = true;
    default:
      $this->active = false;}}

$active = $this->active(); // returns active
$this->active(true); // set active to true

$this->active('true');
$this->active('false'); // those will set active to false
$this->active(false);
```

in this case, calling the function without args (or with an empty string) returns the value, calling it with true sets it to true, and calling it with any other argument sets it to false